# A tiny library implementing the Elm Architecture in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, elm

Elm is a pure functional language for the front-end. It enforces an architecture that allows programs to stay pure in an event-based setting.

This simple header-only library implements a variant of the the Elm Architecture for C++17. Its small footprint and simplicity makes it easy to understand and quick to get started.

#### Features

The architecture supports running commands in parallel as asynchronous tasks, as well as in a immediate fashion.

#### Example Program

This example utilizes both direct and deferred action modes. It initializes by immediately increasing a conuter, then it manipulates the counter at a later time by deferring commands for later execution. To demonstrate the asynchronicity of the library the user can also enter a number in order to increase or decrease the counter.

```
#include "elm-architecture/elm-architecture.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace elm = elm_architecture;

// Model

struct model_type {
    int counter = 0;
};

// Msg

struct increase {};

struct decrease {};

struct user_increase {
    int value;
};

using message_type = std::variant<increase, decrease, user_increase>;

std::shared_future<message_type>
delayed_increase(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) {
    return std::async(
               std::launch::async,
               [delay]( ) -> message_type {
                   std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
                   return increase {};
               })
        .share( );
}

std::shared_future<message_type>
delayed_decrease(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) {
    return std::async(
               std::launch::async,
               [delay]( ) -> message_type {
                   std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
                   return decrease {};
               })
        .share( );
}

std::shared_future<message_type>
ask_user( ) {
    return std::async(
               std::launch::async,
               []( ) -> message_type {
                   int amount = 0;
                   std::cin >> amount;
                   return user_increase {amount};
               })
        .share( );
}

// Update

struct update_fn {
    using return_type = elm::return_type<model_type, message_type>;

    static auto
    update(const model_type& mod, const increase&) -> return_type {
        auto next = mod;
        next.counter += 1;
        std::cout << "Increasing counter from " << mod.counter << " to " << next.counter << std::endl;
        return {next, {}};
    }

    static auto
    update(const model_type& mod, const decrease&) -> return_type {
        auto next = mod;
        next.counter -= 1;
        std::cout << "Decreasing counter from " << mod.counter << " to " << next.counter << std::endl;
        return {next, {}};
    }

    static auto
    update(const model_type& mod, const user_increase& msg) -> return_type {
        auto next = mod;
        next.counter += msg.value;
        std::cout << "User increasing counter from " << mod.counter << " to " << next.counter << std::endl;
        return {next, {ask_user( )}};
    }
};

// Event Loop

int
main( ) {
    elm::start_eventloop<model_type, message_type, update_fn>({
        increase {},
        delayed_increase(std::chrono::milliseconds {1500}),
        delayed_decrease(std::chrono::milliseconds {1000}),
        delayed_increase(std::chrono::milliseconds {400}),
        ask_user( ),
    });
}
```

#### The library

```
#pragma once
#include <deque>
#include <future>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

namespace elm_architecture {

// A command can either be a deferred command (shared_future) or
// invoked directly.
template <typename Model, typename Msg>
using command_type = std::variant<std::shared_future<Msg>, Msg>;

// The return type for the update functions, a new model and a
// list of actions to take after.
template <typename Model, typename Msg>
using return_type = std::tuple<Model, std::vector<command_type<Model, Msg>>>;

// Start the eventloop with a given list of initial actions to take
template <typename Model, typename Msg, typename Update>
auto
start_eventloop(const std::vector<command_type<Model, Msg>>& init = {}) {
    auto                                 model = Model {};
    std::deque<command_type<Model, Msg>> pending{init.begin(), init.end()};
    std::vector<std::shared_future<Msg>> in_progress;

    while(pending.size( ) > 0 || in_progress.size( ) > 0) {
        // Step One: Apply all pending events and remove them
        while(pending.size( ) > 0) {
            const auto& item = pending.front( );
            if(std::holds_alternative<std::shared_future<Msg>>(item)) {
                in_progress.push_back(std::get<std::shared_future<Msg>>(item));
            } else {
                const auto& msg             = std::get<Msg>(item);
                const auto  visitor         = [&model](const auto& msg) { return Update::update(model, msg); };
                auto [next_model, commands] = std::visit(visitor, msg);
                std::copy(commands.begin( ), commands.end( ), std::back_inserter(pending));
                model = next_model;
            }
            pending.pop_front( );
        }

        // Step Two: Pause the loop, the only way we get more events now is by polling
        // until one of the pending events finishes.
        {
            for(auto future = in_progress.begin( ); future != in_progress.end( ); ++future) {
                if(future->wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds {1}) == std::future_status::ready) {
                    pending.push_back(future->get( ));
                    in_progress.erase(future);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
} // namespace elm_architecture
```

This project can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/simon-the-sourcerer-ab/elm-architecture-cpp).